# Dynamic 404 page

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

Is it possible to create a dynamic 404 page that works just like any other page?

I have tried multiple extensions but I can't get any of them to work.
I'm using CoolURI

Comment: What is your definition of dynamic in this context?

Comment: @Zeritor I think that he wants to display like different phrases that he grabs from a DB or something (this is an example...)

Comment: @silentw Yes. Now the 404 page is just static.

Comment: Ah ok, @Patrik, what kind of information? Just random or more data specific to the error?

Comment: @Zeritor Preferably I would like the 404 page to work like any other page in the cms so that people without much knowledge can change content. For example if I create a regular page with the name 404 and set it in the typoscript. Or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have RealURL extension installed then you can set in your typo3conf/localconf.php line

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/404/';
```

Then create page called "404" in TYPO3 tree.

Comment: Ah. Missed that. Thanks. Haven't got it working yet. Seems like CoolUri overrides it and when I disable cooluri something else is redirecting the user to the startpage...

Comment: Maybe you installed some other extension that redirects user if "404 not found". Try to deinstall as many as you can. Also if you deinstall CoolUri then you should put smth like $TYPO3_CONF_VARS['FE']['pageNotFound_handling'] = '/index.php?id=99';

Comment: All extensions are uninstalled... But same problem. I'm not uninstalling cooluri. Just disabling the 404 redirect. Feels like it can be htaccess or something.

Comment: There was a htaccess redirect to index.php. But in some way that have to be there or else the user is not sent to the cms.

Comment: Well. I dont know CoolUri but RealUrl has option like: postVarSet_failureMode. If set to "redirect_goodUpperDir" then it redirects to first known path. Maybe there is something similar in CoolUri that sends you to root.

Comment: I could not find any setting like that. I think I'll ask my colleague. He has a little more knowledge about how our system is setup. It's a very customized typo3 installation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found also such coniguration dfoe CoolUri: <pagenotfound>
      <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
        <behavior type="redirect"><![CDATA[/404/]]></behavior>
    </pagenotfound>

Comment: Yeah, that was what I hade before only the type was page not redirect. But changing that to redirect work wonders :)